# Divisibility in $\mathbb F_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For any prime $p$ and nonzero $a\in \mathbb{F}_p$ prove that for all positive integers $n$, $x^{p^n}-x+na$ is divisible by $x^p-x+a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Can anyone give me some hints to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried dividing with remainder?

Comment: I have tried the case when n=2. After a very long division, I have the result to be true. How can I generalize to general n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, note that $$x^{p^n} - x + n a = \sum_{i=1}^n(x^{p^i}-x^{p^{i-1}} + a)$$

I claim that every term of the sum is divisible by your polynomial. In fact, the first term of the sum is divisible by the second term, and so on. Better than that, the first term is the $p$-th power of the second term, and so on. Can you prove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE Igor.

Comment: @BillDubuque So that's where you hang out!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ \ x^p\!-x+a:\ \color{#c00}{x^p\! \equiv x\!-\!a},\ $ therefore, by $\rm\color{#0a0}{induction,}$ and Frobenius $\rm\color{blue}{(Frob)}$

$\ \ \ \begin{eqnarray}&&\ x^{p^2}\! = (\color{#c00}{x^p})^p\equiv (\color{#c00}{x\!-\!a})^p \overset{\color{blue}{\rm Frob}}\equiv \color{#c00}{x^p}\! - a \equiv \color{#c00}{x\!-\!a}-a \equiv x\!-\!2a \\
&\Rightarrow&\ \cdots \\
 &\Rightarrow&\ x^{p^n}\! = (\color{#0a0}{x^{p^{n-1}}})^p \equiv (\color{#0a0}{x\!-\!(n\!-\!1)a})^p \overset{\color{blue}{\rm Frob}}\equiv \color{#c00}{x^p}\! - (n\!-\!1) a \equiv (\color{#c00}{x\!-a})-\!(n\!-\!1)a) \equiv x\!-\!na  \end{eqnarray} $

Thus $\ x^{p^n}\!-x+na\equiv 0\quad $ **QED**

Comment: (That's not a hint, it's a proof!)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You mean hints don't end with **QED**?